# Disabling autoplay for mp3

Tags: html, css, autostart

I have tried to disable autoplay with no success.

Here's my code:

```
<embed height="17" src="1GasolineSample.mp3" autoplay="false" type="audio/mpeg"  width="60" controls="console">
```

Failed attempts:

- removing `autoplay` completely
- changing `autoplay` to `autostart` and `AutoStart`
- setting `autoplay`/`autostart`/`AutoStart` to zero
- setting `autoplay`/`autostart`/`AutoStart` to one
- setting `autoplay`/`autostart`/`AutoStart` to true
- setting param name="AutoStart" value equal to 0

No changes in behavior occurred. Browser closing and refreshing made no difference.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Try to remove the:**

```
autoplay="false"
```

This attribute makes the browser render this information and may replay it regardless.

**If this does not work add the:**

```
autoplay="false"
```

To you HTML 'source' tag.

**Vote up if it help brother.**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the autoplay attribute all together.

I suggest using the HTML5 AUDIO tag `<audio>` that way you can include controls and other features. It's also a good idea to include other formats to make sure any browser can play it.

```
<audio controls="controls">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
<source src="1GasolineSample.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="1GasolineSample.ogg"  type="audio/ogg">
<source src="1GasolineSample.wav"  type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)
**Autoplay** - A Boolean attribute; if specified (even if the value is "false"!), the audio will automatically begin playback as soon as it can do so, without waiting for the entire audio file to finish downloading.

Comment: Thank you. This got the autoplay to stop. But, when I manually try to play the mp3, it does not.

Comment: Are you using an HTML5 doctype? It may also be the particular browser that doesn't play mp3 so you'll have to include other formats.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
<embed height="17" src="1GasolineSample.mp3" autoplay="false" type="audio/mpeg"  width="60" controls="console">
```

use:

```
<audio controls src="1GasolineSample.mp3">
```

This will stop it from autoplaying.

Comment: Thank you. Using the "audio" tag made it very easy to embed players for mp3 and wav, and I can also use the "video" tag similarly to embed a player for mp4.

Answer (score 0):

autoplay doesn't need a value...  include or exclude the attribute...

this will play automatically:

```
<video src="source.mp4" autoplay />
```

this will not

```
<video src="source.mp4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will disable browser from autoplaying audio.

**HTML**

```
<audio type="audio/wav" id="audio" autoplay="false" autostart="false"></audio>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#audio').attr("src","path_to_audio.wav");
$('#audio').play();
```