# How to download public files from google storage using html download tag

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I  have stored files on `GCP` storage and made `public`. I have a public URL for GCP files.

when I am tried to download these files using HTML download tag, its opening autoplay embedded player but not downloading files

below sample HTML code:

```
html
body

a href="stroage public url" download="MyGoogleLogo">download me <a

body
html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting question, since you cannot disable autoplay in Cloud Storage, I was trying to [change different metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895488/11293192) ('Content-Type', 'Content-Disposition'), but *.mp3 files are still playing in the in-browser player, SO thread is quite old and this solution does not work. Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307689/disabling-autoplay-for-mp3), how to disable [autoplay](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp) in HTML.

Also, you can reach your goal using [Google Storage SignedURLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).